# Math in this anagram substring search algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, anagram

In the following code:

```
function sherlockAndAnagrams(s) {
var pairs = 0;
var subStrings = {};

//find all substrings of our string, count them in a hash
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    for(var j = i; j < s.length; j++){
        let tempSubString = s.substring(i, j+1).split("").sort().join("");
        if(subStrings[tempSubString]){
            subStrings[tempSubString] +=1;
        }else{
            subStrings[tempSubString] = 1;
        }
    }
}

//****ATTENTION******
for(var keys in subStrings){
    if(subStrings[keys] > 1){
    let temp = (subStrings[keys])*(subStrings[keys]-1)/2;
       pairs += temp;
   }
}
return pairs;
}
```

I am unsure how the math behind this formula works:

subString[keys])*(subString[keys]-1)/2

Assuming s = "kkkk", there would be 6 anagrams of "k"s

Can someone please explain this?

In addition, this kind of tells me that I may be a bit short on certain type of math. If you could advise me a good material to study for figuring out math like this I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is following: you have `n` words that are anagrams of each other. How many pairs of anagrams can you select from there? This is a simple [combinatoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) question with a known answer: [binominal coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of `(n,2)` which is `n*(n-1)/2`.

The logic is that if you count all anagrams, the first anagram you can select in `n` ways, the second in `n-1` ways but each anagram will be considered twice: once as `ab=ba` and another time as `ba=ab`

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation and letting me know the exact mathematical term for this problem is! The highest math class I took is business calculus (plus it's been years since I took those classes) and I was wondering if you have any book/material recommendation for me to review as I study more algorithm.